# BeautifulSoup error: Invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 (beautifulsoup) in python 3.2, and this is my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import bs4
import re

webpage = urlopen(‘http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kanyewest/workoutplan.html’).read()
```

It gives:

```
    webpage = urlopen(‘http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kanyewest/workoutplan.html’).read()
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Indeed, Python 3.2 places the marker a little further along, I used Python 3.4 which indicates earlier that there is something fishy. The cause is the same, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using ASCII quote characters; `‘` is not a legal quote in Python syntax.

Use a *text editor* to edit your Python source code, not one that replaces plain ASCII quotes with fancy quotes.

Use `'` or `"`:

```
webpage = urlopen('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kanyewest/workoutplan.html').read()
webpage = urlopen("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kanyewest/workoutplan.html").read()
```

See [*String and Bytes literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for the exhaustive list of options.

Comment: Thank you, I actually copy pasted this code from somewhere else, and it used different quotes.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: then that blog used a fancy-shmancy word processor and that mucked up their code samples. :-)